# Unknown FFmpeg error when I try to download a video from microsoft teams with destreamer

Tags: ffmpeg, microsoft-teams

I need to fix the problem:

```
"video_name:" Permission denied
Unknown FFmpeg error
```

which I got when I tried to download a video from microsoft teams by using destreamer.

Some months ago it worked perfectly. I installed also the [new release](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) of ffmpeg, but the result is the same.

Comment: Run destreamer with the verbose option "-v" to get more details about the error. Also, try with changing your download path "-o path/to/output/dir" instead of /video.

Comment: Hello @Vencat thank you very much for your suggestions; it works. Now there is a new problem: the download speed is low and the access token is good only for 57 minutes (I need more than 1 hour to download a video)